# Does Arduino sent output to TX pinout?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am beginner at Arduino,i tried to read as much as i can but i am not sure if i am doing good.I would like to send a specific code for a (non PC) device through the TX pinout when i push the button which is wired to the Pin 2.I have writtem this small code to check it:

```
int buttonUPpin = 2;
int UpinStatus=LOW;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(buttonUPpin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
digitalWrite(buttonUPpin,HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

UpinStatus=digitalRead(buttonUPpin);

if(LOW==UpinStatus)
{
Serial.print('A');
digitalWrite(1,LOW);

}

}
```

When i push the button i can see at serial monitor the 'A' character but i am not sure if this character was also sent out to the TX pinout since the TX led is not blinking only the RX led.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set pinMode for pin 1 and using pin 1 will interfere with the serial monitor (never use 0 and 1).

```
#define buttonUPpin = 2;
#define LedPin = 3;
int UpinStatus = LOW;


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(buttonUPpin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
    pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
    // digitalWrite(buttonUPpin,HIGH);  // Don't think this is right

}

void loop() 
{
    UpinStatus=digitalRead(buttonUPpin);
    if(LOW==UpinStatus)
    {
       Serial.print('A');
       digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);  // Not sure if High or Low depends on you circuit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start the `Serial` it takes over the `TX` and `RX` pins and it ignores pin mode settings (and `digitalWrite` too).

Btw `TX` and `RX` LEDs are driven by USB to Serial interface chip so you don't have any control of it either.

Comment: in this case how can i be sure that the desired output was sent out?

Comment: If you mean TX/RX LEDs, then they are blinking if you're receiving data from computer (RX), or if you're sending data to the computer (TX). If you mean logic state on pin, you can't use pins 0 and 1 with Arduino Serial.

Comment: Rx led is blinking when i push button2 but there is no tx led blinking in the same time(to send to the tx pinout)